# Android: Application context issue in in-App purchase Dungeon class

Tags: android

I have successfully implemented in-App purchase in my app.But i want to show the dungeons page under one parent class using TabgroupActivity.

But it never allows my app to do  any kind of transaction, showing a massage that "you can't make purchase using this version of market" kind of error.But it works fine with the normal class.The context i am using is getParent().

Can anyone help me ?